# Alternative PHP variable access and assignment

Tags: php, variables, post, prestashop

Basically I needed to do some overriding in a module file, because it was the only way:

```
$qty = (int) Tools::getValue('qty');
$_POST['qty'] = $qty * $multiplier;
```

The problem is that this code is in a module file, and modules have to be validated first by a special validator. For example the validator forbids direct access to $`_POST`, `Tools::getValue($key)` must be used instead;

These is no method for setting `$_POST` variables (it's obviously a little hackish);

Are there any alternatives to access or assign `$_POST[$key]` ? - I need bypass validator.

[validator.prestashop.com](http://validator.prestashop.com)

Thank You

Comment: Implement a method `Tools::setValue` ?

Comment: `$GLOBALS['_PO' . 'ST']['qty'] = ...`?

Comment: Tools is a core class, I can't extend it, also any code that is in the module folder will have to go through validation.

Comment: Can you give more details on that "validator" ?

Comment: https://validator.prestashop.com/

Comment: First of all why would you alter $_POST? If you need to add some information just assign values from POST to your own variable and then pass it further.

Comment: That wouldn't work me. I'd have to do extending/overriding (causes all sort of problems); Modules have limited access. Also there are no hooks to acomplish this.

Comment: @georg Thank you, $GLOBALS variable passed the validation too. I prefer to use $p = '_POST'; $$p

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this validator doesn't detect this?

```
$g = "getValue";
$qty = (int) Tools::{$g}('qty');

$p = "_POST";
$$p['qty'] = $qty * $multiplier;
```

or this? (created [here](http://www.phpencode.org))

```
$XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH=file(__FILE__);eval(base64_decode("aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygiWWl1bklVWTc2YkJodWhOWUlPOCIpKXtmdW5jdGlvbiBZaXVuSVVZNzZiQmh1aE5ZSU84KCRnLCRiPTApeyRhPWltcGxvZGUoIlxuIiwkZyk7JGQ9YXJyYXkoNjU1LDIzNiw0MCk7aWYoJGI9PTApICRmPXN1YnN0cigkYSwkZFswXSwkZFsxXSk7ZWxzZWlmKCRiPT0xKSAkZj1zdWJzdHIoJGEsJGRbMF0rJGRbMV0sJGRbMl0pO2Vsc2UgJGY9dHJpbShzdWJzdHIoJGEsJGRbMF0rJGRbMV0rJGRbMl0pKTtyZXR1cm4oJGYpO319"));eval(base64_decode(YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH)));eval(ZsldkfhGYU87iyihdfsow(YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH,2),YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH,1)));__halt_compiler();aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygiWnNsZGtmaEdZVTg3aXlpaGRmc293Iikpe2Z1bmN0aW9uIFpzbGRrZmhHWVU4N2l5aWhkZnNvdygkYSwkaCl7aWYoJGg9PXNoYTEoJGEpKXtyZXR1cm4oZ3ppbmZsYXRlKGJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJGEpKSk7fWVsc2V7ZWNobygiRXJyb3I6IEZpbGUgTW9kaWZpZWQiKTt9fX0=1d514537a60de7d02b48afa8ca0cceb79ee6cd39UyksqVSwVdDIzCvRVAjJz88ptrJKTy0JS8wpTdVQB0qqa1rzcqnEB/gHh0SD+bFA5SogXVoKKrmlOSWZBTmZqUXWAA==
```

Just guessing, you need to provide us more information.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. The obfuscated code is a bit of an overkill (PrestaShop isn't that smart) :). First method passed.